# Python + numpy: same code, different numerical result

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing, reproducible-research

I've identified some really funny behavior that I am curious about. Ultimately, I want code that is totally reproducible for scientific computing reasons.

Anyway, here's a snippet of code with output. And as you can see, the same computations lead to slightly different outcomes.

```
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
P = np.random.randn(100, 100)

for i in range(10):
    a1 = P.dot(x)
    a2 = P.dot(x)
    b1 = x.dot(a1)
    b2 = x.dot(a2)
    if b1 != b2:
        break

print 'i = {}'.format(i)
print np.abs(a1 - a2).max()
print np.abs(b1 - b2)
print b2
```

And here's the output:

```
i = 1
0.0
1.7763568394e-15
-10.2398857939
```

My two variables, `x` and `P` are just 1d and 2d numpy arrays. Yet somehow, the identical simple calculation gives different results. Moreover, on different iterations of the loop, the trial that fails to give the same result varies. In this case, for example, the `i = 0` trial had no problem, but the calculation failed to give the same results for `i = 1`.

Interestingly, if I don't save the intermediate values in `a1` and `a2`, then the result is identical:

```
for i in range(10000):
    b1 = x.dot(P.dot(x))
    b2 = x.dot(P.dot(x))
    if b1 != b2:
        break

print 'i = {}'.format(i)
print np.abs(b1 - b2)
```

With output:

```
i = 9999
0.0
```

Any idea what's going on here??

Comment: Can you provide examples of the x and P values, so we can reproduce this behaviou?

Comment: Edited above to make `x` and `P` random. Same issue. It clearly has to do with the order of additions in the dot product, but why is that variable? And how can I be sure that it's the same every time. Python: 2.7; numpy 1.11.1

Comment: I'm betting the answer here relates to floating-point math.

Comment: I cant reproduce it on Python 3.5. Getting expected result `i = 9`,
'0.0' and  `0.0` for the first three printouts.

Comment: For "totally reproducible" code, don't forget to set the seed. ;-)  I can't duplicate your problem myself.  I'm using Python 3, numpy 1.11.1.  Now 3.55e-14 is REALLY close to zero, but not actually zero and I can't see why it wouldn't be here.  Floating point math can give you weird answers for x - y, but shouldn't for x - x (if both are 4-byte floats)

Comment: Still a problem with numpy seed set. See above

Comment: I can't reproduce on python 2.7.6 64 bit on linux w/ gcc version 4.8.2. Are you using python 32 bit? That likely doesn't matter but when grasping at straws...

Comment: Hard to see how it could be floating-point error; with the exact same inputs, truncation and roundoff should happen in exactly the same way. I'm running the same configuration as tdelaney, and I also can't repro.

Comment: I wonder if this could be something weird with OS X. When I run the same code on my linux cluster, I don't get an error. But I get it on both of my Macs

Comment: Just a guess: Some processors have floating point units with 80-bit precision in their internal registers. If an intermediate result is kept in a register for the next operation, and not stored in memory, it retains its 80-bit precision. But if a number is stored in memory, it will have 64 bits of precision. So depending which intermediate results were stored in memory, the final result may have tiny differences. Which computer and which processor do you have?

Comment: -1 for generic suggestions about floating-point. As the example is currently written floating point should make no obvious difference. On python 3.6 OSX I can't reproduce the reported behavior though. And I don't have a clue how this behavior could arise; nor how the absence or presence of temporaries could make a difference. My best guess is that maybe the different memory alignment of the temporaries could cause some BLAS routine to pick a subtly different implementation, which results in a different order of operations in the summation of the dot.

Comment: For instance, some vectorized loops may be written as a short loop over the non-aligned part of the array, plus an unrolled/SIMDed loop over the aligned parts of the array. This might also explain the influence of the temporary. Note that numpy still makes a temporary array even if you dont hang on to it with a python reference; but since python knows it can free the temporary array immediately when written in-line without a python reference to it, the numpy allocator is likely to reuse the same array directly in the line below, thus giving the same result.

Comment: One more comment wrt scientific reproducibility; when it comes to robustness against floating-point noise, I think its more cautious to assume there will be noise, and that you can show your algorithm produces functionally identical results given that noise, than to show there is no numerical noise. That is a wildly unrealistic expectation for any algorithm 'in the wild' anyway; as the irreproducibility across OSes and so on shows, even for such a seemingly innocent example.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Floating point operations are still a deterministic. Doing the same operations with the same input should yield the same result. I would guess that the behavior you are observing is caused by a hardware fault.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it doesn't appear to be reproducible on modern versions of Python and Numpy.